# Is there a condensation of a closed subset of $\kappa^\omega$ onto $\kappa^\omega\setminus A$ …?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, descriptive-set-theory

Let $\aleph_1\le\kappa<c$ and $A\subset \kappa^{\omega}$ such that $\lvert A\rvert\le\kappa$.

1. Is there a condensation (i.e. a bijective continuous mapping) of a closed subset of $\kappa^\omega$ onto $\kappa^\omega\setminus A$?

Let $B$ be a closed subset of $\kappa^{\omega}$ such that $w(B)=\kappa$ and $A\subset B$, $\lvert A\rvert\le\kappa$.

2. Is there a condensation from a closed subset of $\kappa^\omega$  onto $B\setminus A$?

Note that the first question is equivalent to the second.

Would a positive answer to the question be true for a weaker condition for the mapping to be a continuous surjection ?